# How to filter C# Winform datagridview that was created with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm astonished there isn't even a filter property attached to datagridview and I'm getting on my nerve, I can find examples for filtering Datagridview that was binded programmatically, I cannot find any example on how to filter a datagridview that was generated by Visual Studio.

So please can someone tell me how to filter this stuff ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put a filter on the BindingSource :

```
bindingSource.Filter = "Age < 21";
```

Answer (score 1):

You place the filter on the DataSource that is driving your DataGridView - for example, I have this code on a DataGridView that allows for user filtering and is called on a postback:

```
VisitsDataSource.FilterExpression = "1 = 2";
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure to understand fully but will try.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx). You have provide a BindingSource as the DataSource of the DataGridView rather than the DataTable itself.

```
BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
source1.DataSource = yourDataTable;    

//The Filter string can include Boolean expressions.
source1.Filter = "email='samikram@live.com'"

// Set the data source for the DataGridView.
datagridview1.DataSource = source1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JustinD, I suppose you talk about ASP.NET.

I forgot to say I'm using Winform with BindingSource.